# Multiselect options not getting selected while editing existing data

Tags: php, multi-select

I have a multi-select option, the selected option values of which are stored in a databsse as csv separated values like HJ,JB. While editing the data, i receive the value in a php variable as:

```
$usercenter = $row['user_center']; //HJ,JB
```

I am getting all the `center_id` and `center_value` items from the DB and all the options and values are displayed in dropdown. But the already selected values are not getting selected in code below:

```php
<select id="center" name="center[]" multiple="multiple" size="5" tabindex="6">
    <optgroup label=""><?php
        $q = $conn->prepare("
            SELECT center_id,center_name
            FROM center 
            WHERE region = :region 
            && status = :status
        "); 
        $q->execute(array(':region' => "$userregion",':status' => "Enabled"));
        $data = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $myArray = explode(',', $usercenter); //original selected values ("HJ,JB")

        foreach ($data as $opt) {
            if(in_array($opt, $myArray)) { 
                $sel = ' selected="selected" '; 
                echo '<option ' . $sel . ' value="' . $opt['center_id'] . '">' . $opt['center_name'] . '</option>'; 
            }else{ 
                echo '<option value="' . $opt['center_id'] . '">' . $opt['center_name'] . '</option>'; 
            }
        }?>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

The issue seems like the database values in `$row['user_center']` contains comma separated **values** of the select option. But the dropdown display contains both **option names and values**. Something is wrong with my `in_array` comparison.

There are no errors. Dropdown displaying with all items. What am i doing incorrectly ?? Requesting help!!

Comment: You did a mistake in `in_array` condition, your condition should be like: `if(in_array($opt['center_name'], $myArray))` , because you are comparing center name with `$myArray` values.

Comment: @turivishal  You are correct. Thank you...And it is in_array($opt['center_id']..not in_array($opt['center_name'] as $myArray contains values..center_id.

Comment: Oh sorry, i thought its `center_name`, hope you have resolved you problem.